# Iterating over an array in Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm retrieving data from an external API in JSON format and sending that data to my view. The issue I'm having is, one of the properties within the Object is an Array of Objects. Following the Pug Documentation ([Pug Iteration](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)), I can successfully iterate over the Array like so:

```js
block content
  .row
    each item in data.array
      .col-md-3
        .well
          img(src=`${item.media.m}`)
          h5 #{item.title}
          p by #{item.author}
```

However, the Array stores 20 values and ideally, I would like to iterate over four values at a time so I can achieve the following output:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="well">
      <img src="https://localhost/frank_the_pug.jpg">
      <h5>Frank the Pug</h5>
      <p>by MIB</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="well">
      <img src="https://localhost/frank_the_pug2.jpg">
      <h5>Frank the Pug 2</h5>
      <p>by MIB</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

JSON Structure

```
{
  "string": "string",
  "string": "string",
  "array": [
    {
      "string": "string",
      "media": {
        "m": "string"
      }
    },
    {
      "string": "string",
      "media": {
        "m": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As far as I can understand your problem, you should probably loop again, or perhaps change the way you format your data, could you perhaps show your data structure?

Comment: Hi Fabian, you're right I need to loop again somehow before I output the `.row` div, so I can output one `.row` div with four `.col-md-3 divs`. How would you go about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can first group items by 4 then use two nested loops to iterate over groups and over items in groups

```
- const groupBy4 = arr => arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
-    let last = acc[acc.length - 1]
-    if(last.length === 4) {
-      acc.push(last = []);
-    }
-    last.push(item)
-    return acc;
- }, [[]])

each group in groupBy4(items)
  .row
    each item in group
      .col-md-3
        .well
          img(src=item.media.m)
          h5 #{item.title}
          p by #{item.author}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yury. This looks good, what would be best practice in terms of having the groupBy4() function in a separate file and then include it into our pug template?

Comment: You could pass function in locals by requiring it from separate file.